# Простенький svg редактор

Tags: svg

Есть ли в этом мире простенький svg редактор, как paint? Что бы можно было нарисовать простенький рисунок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Воспользуйтесь Inkscape - он прост в использовании и распространяется бесплатно.

Comment: Прямо в браузере можно рисовать при помощи Method Draw

Comment: Inkscape построен на SVG. Вполне логичный выбор.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к тематике сайта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чаще всего я пользуюсь [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/), он русский.
Ещё онлайн-редакторами:
[Онлайн-редакторы векторной графики (сборник)](http://www.newart.ru/htm/flash/vector_drawing.php)
А помогая переводить статьи по svg из [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG) на русский язык - незаметно и сам обучаюсь.

Ах, - да, намедни украл у одного дяденьки классный редактор кривых Безье, ну и перевёл его на свой язык. (был на инглиш)

```css
@use postcss-cssnext;
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600);

:root { --ad-Color-sec: #0da;
        --ad-Color-hov: linear-gradient(to top, #044, #088, #044);
        --ad-Color-del: linear-gradient(to top, #222, #666, #222);
        --ad-Color-prim: #111;
        --ad-Color-foot: #122;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.ad-no {text-transform: none;}
.ad-App {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* основной макет */
.ad-Container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
}
    .ad-Container-main {
        height: 100%;
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
        .ad-Container-svg {
            height: 100%;
            flex: 1;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background: #f3f3f3;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ddd, #f3f3f3, #ddd);
        }
    
    .ad-Container-controls {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20rem;
        background: var(--ad-Color-prim);
    }
    .ad-Container-controls ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 6px;
    }
    .ad-Container-controls ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 30px;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    }

.ad-Foot {
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
}
    .ad-Foot-list {
        flex: 1;
    }
        .ad-Foot-item {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: .7rem;
            color: var(--ad-Color-foot);
        }
        .ad-Foot-item + .ad-Foot-item {
            margin-top: .5rem;
        }
            .ad-Foot-highlight {
                padding-bottom: .04rem;
                border-bottom: 2px solid var(--ad-Color-sec);
                font-weight: bold;
            }
    
    .ad-Foot-meta {
        margin-left: 2rem;
        text-align: right;
        line-height: 1.4;
        font-size: .7rem;
        color: var(--ad-Color-prim);
    }
        .ad-Foot-meta a {
            text-decoration: underline;
            color: var(--ad-Color-prim);
        }


.ad-SVG {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
    .ad-Grid {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #eee;
        stroke-width: 1px;
    }
    .ad-Grid.is-hidden {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ad-Path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #555;
        stroke-width: 4px;
        stroke-linecap: round;
    }
    .ad-Point {
        cursor: pointer;
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: #555;
        stroke-width: 5px;
        transition: fill .2s;
    }
    .ad-Point:hover,
    .ad-PointGroup.is-active .ad-Point {
        fill: var(--ad-Color-sec);
    }
    .ad-PointGroup--first .ad-Point {
        stroke: var(--ad-Color-sec);
    }
    .ad-Anchor {
        opacity: .5;
    }
    .ad-PointGroup.is-active .ad-Anchor {
        opacity: 1;
    }
        .ad-Anchor-point {
            cursor: pointer;
            fill: #fff;
            stroke: #888;
            stroke-width: 5px;
        }
        .ad-Anchor-line {
            stroke: #888;
            stroke-width: 1px;
            stroke-dasharray: 5 5;
        }

/* управление справа */
.ad-Controls {
    overflow: auto;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 2rem;
}
    .ad-Controls :first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .ad-Controls-title {
        margin: 1rem 0;
        font-size: .8rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
    }
        .ad-Controls-container {
            display: flex;
        }
        .ad-Controls-container + .ad-Controls-container {
            margin-top: 1rem;
        }

.ad-Control {
    flex: 1;
}
    .ad-Control-label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: .5rem;
        /*text-transform: uppercase;*/
        font-size: .7rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: color(var(--ad-Color-prim) l(+75%));
    }

.ad-Result {
    height: 5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: var(--ad-Color-foot);
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
    .ad-Result-textarea {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        resize: none;
        border: none;
        background: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        font-size: .7rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 1.8;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .ad-Result-textarea:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

/* элементы управления */
.ad-Button {
    padding: .8rem 1rem;
    background: var(--ad-Color-del);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background .2s;
    /*text-transform: uppercase;*/
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: .08rem;
    color: #fff;
}
.ad-Button:focus,
.ad-Button:hover {
    outline: 0;
    background: var(--ad-Color-hov);
}
.ad-Button--delete {
    background: var(--ad-Color-del);
}
.ad-Button--delete:focus,
.ad-Button--delete:hover {
    background: color(var(--ad-Color-hov) l(+2%));
}
.ad-Button--reset {
    background: var(--ad-Color-del);
}
.ad-Button--reset:focus,
.ad-Button--reset:hover {
    background: color(var(--ad-Color-hov) l(+2%));
}

.ad-Text {
    height: 18px;
    width: 2rem;
    background: color(var(--ad-Color-prim) l(+10%));
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: .6rem;
    color: #fff;
}
.ad-Text:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: color(var(--ad-Color-prim) l(+20%));
}

.ad-Checkbox-input {
    display: none;
}
.ad-Checkbox-fake {
    position: relative;
    height: 14px;
    width: 2rem;
    background: color(var(--ad-Color-prim) l(+10%));
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.ad-Checkbox-fake::after {
    content: "";
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: 0;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    background: color(var(--ad-Color-prim) l(+10%));
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.ad-Checkbox-input:checked + .ad-Checkbox-fake::after {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    border-color: var(--ad-Color-sec);
}

.ad-Choices {
    display: flex;
    width: 12rem;
}
    .ad-Choice {
        flex: 1;
    }
        .ad-Choice-input {
            display: none;
        }
        .ad-Choice-fake {
            padding: .6rem;
            background: color(var(--ad-Color-prim) l(+10%));
            border: 4px solid transparent;
            transition: border .2s;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
            font-size: .8rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .ad-Choice:first-child .ad-Choice-fake {
            border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
        }
        .ad-Choice:last-child .ad-Choice-fake {
            border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
        }
        .ad-Choice-input:checked + .ad-Choice-fake {
            border-color: var(--ad-Color-sec);
        }

.ad-Range {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
    .ad-Range-text {
        margin-left: .5rem;
    }
    .ad-Range-input {
        width: 100%;
        height: 14px;
        appearance: none;
        border-radius: 30px;
        background: color(var(--ad-Color-prim) l(+10%));
    }
    .ad-Range-input:focus {
        outline: 0;
        background: color(var(--ad-Color-prim) l(+20%));
    }
    /* thumb */
    .ad-Range-input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        border: 4px solid #fff;
        background: color(var(--ad-Color-prim) l(+10%));
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: border .2s;
    }
    .ad-Range-input::-moz-range-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        border: 4px solid #fff;
        background: color(var(--ad-Color-prim) l(+10%));
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: border .2s;
    }

    .ad-Range-input:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb,
    .ad-Range-input:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        border-color: var(--ad-Color-sec);
    }
    .ad-Range-input:hover::-moz-range-thumb,
    .ad-Range-input:focus::-moz-range-thumb {
        border-color: var(--ad-Color-sec);
    }
```

```html
<div
     id="app"
     class="ad-App">
</div>
```

К сожалению, размер кода превышает здешний лимит, поэтому придётся пользоваться ссылками на "codepen":
Перевод: [SVG-редактор кривых Безье](https://codepen.io/warsan/pen/bObLRr)
Источник: [SVG Path Builder](https://codepen.io/anthonydugois/pen/mewdyZ)

Comment: На этом сайте, к сожалению, [**не приветствуются ответы, содержащие только ссылку**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/199934). Нужно выбрать основное из материалов по ссылке и добавить это прямо в ответ. Но для данного ответа можете этого не делать, ибо вопрос тоже, скорее всего, удалят. Спасибо.

Comment: - Понял, спасибо, внёс изменения...

Comment: @ВарламЕрофеич, добро пожаловать на StackOverflow=)

Comment: - Благодарю, @Arthur, однако здесь так много правил и условностей, что сразу и не привыкнуть.   Почти как в пословице "Стой там - иди сюда", хотя многие требования справедливы...

Comment: @ВарламЕрофеич, несомненно. Полагаю вы знаете `SVG`. Здесь не так уж много изучающих и понимающих его, поэтому каждый участник в какой-то мере ценен для нашего сообщества. Если в дальнейшем заинтересованы поговорить про `SVG`, предлагаю посетить чат, посвящённый ему — https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat . Чтобы отправлять сообщения в любом чате, вам нужно набрать больше 20 репутации, а это как минимум ещё один голос "за" на любом из ваших ответов.